# TypeError: tn.add/removeClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a "sticky" Nav funktion for my Website where the nav bar stick on top when you scroll down till the banner on top is gone.

I've createt this script:

```
var tn = ".topnav"
var tns = ".topnav-scrolled"
var kz = $('#kopfzeile').height();
console.log("tn: " + tn);
console.log("tns: " + tns);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > kz) {
    tn.addClass(tns);
  } else {
    tn.removeClass(tns);
  }
});
```

The Error is:

> TypeError: tn.removeClass is not a function

And

> TypeError: tn.removeClass is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting *is not a function* Error since `tn` is just a string (selector) you can't call `removeClass()` method on it, you should wrap it by `$()` to be a jQuery object, Should be :

```
$(tn).addClass(tns);
//And
$(tn).removeClass(tns);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var tn = ".topnav"
 var tns = ".topnav-scrolled"
 var kz = $('#kopfzeile').height();
 console.log("tn: " + tn);
 console.log("tns: " + tns);
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > kz) {
 $(tn).addClass(tns);
  } else {
 $(tn).removeClass(tns);
 }
 });
```